# Reactive JobScheduler

Tags: android, rx-java, android-jobscheduler

How can I mimic the Android [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) (or [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager)) behaviour with RxJava on Android?

Specifically, I would like to have this functionality

- Awareness of network activity
- Automatic back-off and failure retry

Background: With Android N, connectivity changes are not anymore broadcasted to background threads. To resolve this issue, Google suggests to use JobScheduler/GcmNetworkManager, but I would like to solve it with RxJava.

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN NOT** do it.

With `JobScheduler` Android checks for network connectivity, battery status, charging status etc... Your app process doesn't have to be running. If the conditions are met Android will wake up your app. Android will also batch jobs together saving battery.

To do that with `RxJava` (check for network, battery) you process will have to be running so you are not saving battery.

As you can see from [issue #16](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat/issues/16) of [JobSchedulerCompat](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat) (deprecated) trying to emulate `JobScheduler` on pre-lollipol wastes battery.

Comment: Can't you have an Rx wrapper around a job scheduler that will fire off events (rx-relay)?

Comment: Yes, you could @ZakTaccardi, but then the job scheduler would necessarily run at a time you specified, and not, perhaps, the most battery-efficient time to do so; these job schedulers are about giving up control for a good cause =] Once in the task, you can of course do what you like, perhaps using RxJava and returning in the OnComplete; after 3 min the task will end regardless.